# What is the best build to pubstomp as Mundo jungle?

Tags: league-of-legends

What is the best build to pubstomp as Mundo jungle?  I have seen so many and tried so many but want to know from someone who plays him a lot.

Comment: Pubstomp == Melt Faces?

Comment: For future questions please try to avoid using slang that is not common knowledge :)

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question about what specific build goals you have in mind other than just "pubstomping"? That's not a very good metric for a helpful question or answer. If you let us know what you've tried and what hasn't worked for you, and what you'd like to achieve, we can give you a better answer.

Comment: I feel like this question can't get an "answer" if it uses "pubstomp" which is slang for getting into a group to beat random players using skill and communication and he is asking for individual strength with a champion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=21255

What this guide states is that he is a high ELO jungler that does run mundo.

### Runes

- 9 Flat Attack Speed Reds
- 9 Flat Armor Yellows
- 9 Magic Resistance Per Lvl Blues
- 3 Flat Movement Speed Quints.

Why these runes? Attack speed to clear faster, thus making your clear time ridiculously faster than it already is. Armor yellows and Magic Resist blues to help you survive in the jungle as well as be a monster ganker. And the movement speed quints to help you clear faster and get around the map faster for easier ganks.

### Masteries

Run 9/21/0 grabbing armor pen, improved exhaust, attack speed and attack damage in offense, and magic resist, armor, health, minion damage, and decreased damage in defense.

### Build and Leveling

Start boots and 3 potions, into a heart of gold for increased farm and health, boots of situation, high ap or cc build merc treads, otherwise build ninja tabis, as they are ridiculously good. After that your major core items should be a Frozen mallet for the health, damage, and that overpowered slow it gives, and a Wits End for the attack speed, and stacking magic resist as thats always a good thing nowadays. If you feel the need to tank for your team, build Aegis of the Legion, either more armor or magic resist with transforming that HoG (heart of gold) into a Randuins Omen, or start working on a Force of Nature. More damage would be to build an Atmas Impaler.

As for leveling, Take W at rank 1, Q at 2, W at 3, E at 4, Then prioritize your R, W, Q, E.

### Jungle Route and My Preferred Summoner Spells

The safe way would be to start at wraiths, red, golems, gank, wraiths, blue, gank again. Or if you are feeling ballsy, start wolves, blue, go take their red and then gank. Also take smite and exhaust, as they are your best friends in the jungle. you dont need flash or ghost as your are super tanky, and your ultimate has a low cooldown down ghost built in with the heal.

But thats pretty much it. Ive played him 5 out my last 6 ranked jungling games, and won them all doing just what I posted here. As Saintvicious classifies him, hes at a better spot than Shyvana, as his W can be toggled, and his cleaver basically has no cooldown which means perma-slow.

Comment: Feel free to summarize parts of the guide here on our site. It helps guard against link rot if the guide gets moved later. I usually just note the items and why, jungle route, and skill prioritization.

Comment: I wonder if the person who put this comment in knows that MR isn't really needed for surviving in the jungle.  Additionally, MR per level blues is really slanted towards late game teamfights when the AP Caster generally will be dishing out AOE damage.  Since as Mundo, they shouldn't be wasting their cooldowns to kill you really.

Comment: It would be better if you included that "Saintvicious" is the designated jungler with experience with Dr. Mundo for the professional League of Legends team Counterlogic Gaming. Like user22193 stated, clarify why the guide uses magic resist in the build instead of just saying it helps you be a "monster ganker"(Magic resist/lvl is most likely for future fights, but not essentially for the jungle.) So yeah, always include the "why" in an answer, which should come from experienced, proven to be effective gameplay .